# How to change configuration so php page is shown?

Tags: php, apache

I have the following simple HTML/PHP code in the file `example.php`

```
<html>
<head><title>PHP Example test page</title></head>

<body>

<h4>PHP Example</h4>

<?php
/* Display a text message */
echo “Hello, world! This is my first PHP program.”;
?>

</body>
</html>
```

but the browser is empty when trying to open this page! httpd is running and a simple html page is shown. I added the following two lines to the file `etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`:

```
LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so
AddType application/x-httpd-php        php php5
```

`php` on the command line shows its version 5.3.3. Any idea what configuration is incorrect this time?

Comment: Are smart quotes (“”) valid strings in php? Try changing `echo “Hello, world! This is my first PHP program.”;` to `echo "Hello, world! This is my first PHP program.";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the looks of it you have copy pasted the quotes, which are non standard. Try manually retyping the " characters.